# How to group items within a groupedList on Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: json, listview, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Ok, I've spent the day getting my models, stores and views all setup.
I have the ajax and grouping working fine for my ListView.

My question is, I want to order & group by 'day' and inside of that grouping, I want to group by 'order_id'.

Can this be done? Would it be a new view inside the list's cell?

I'm new to Sencha and have searched all through their docs/google/etc.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: You want to group by 'day' only or nested group by? I guess you are trying to groupby "day" and want to sort by "order_id". If i am right, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I didn't need a list within a list.

I ended up resolving this by changing the JSON format it was receiving and then using `Ext.XTemplate();` looping through using `<tpl for="items">`.

Thanks for the comments anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [grouper](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-grouper) config on Ext.data.Store. You may have to be a bit creative with the logic, but you should be able to accomplish it.